# Does a single REST API call on SharePoint actually create 29 requests?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, performance

This API call

```
https://{siteURL}/sites/...../_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('{name}')/items?$select=Title
```

when viewed through chrome devtools, [image: Chrome DevTools]

creates, apparently, 29 requests ... or am I misunderstanding something? Why would it not be 1 request?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One API call is a single request by definition. None of the 29 requests you see in the dev tools are connected to your call/request. Except for your single GET request that you send.

So 29 requests are all other sorts of calls that your page does when retreiving images, CSS styles, scripts other data.

Comment: I'm no s/w engineer but... the end result is a page of text of maybe 30 lines. If my browser is the client, and requests originate with the client, then who's make the other 29 requests? It's not like it's an initial result, which triggers further calls client side.

Comment: All SharePoint pages make a ton of requests. Even blank SharePoint pages. If you share a full screenshot of your page with the network tab open, I will be able to tell what these requests are.

Comment: Added screenshot - I've cropped out some confidential data.

Comment: Can you now remove the filter? Click on `All` instead of `Other` under your Network tab

Comment: I can only see 3 requests on your screenshot. 1 is your actual call to the REST API and the other two must be some kind of a Chrome extension called walkme

Comment: Walkme looks like a corporate thingy. And that seems to be making all the calls.

Comment: @Maxcot, can you, please accept the answer if it helped you?